# Javascript : object properties aren't recognized

Tags: javascript, oop, object, properties

I have a foo object as follow :

```
var foo =
{   
    "timer" : 
    {
        "hours" : 0, 
        "minutes" : 0, 
        "seconds" : 0,  
        "time" : new Date(1970, 0, 1, foo.timer.hours, foo.timer.minutes, foo.timer.seconds).getTime()                      
    }
};
```

The problem is that foo.timer.hours, foo.timer.minutes and foo.timer.seconds properties in new Date() aren't recognized because javascript console in chrome browser displays that :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timer' of undefined
```

So why foo.timer.hours, foo.timer.minutes and foo.timer.seconds properties in new Date() aren't recognized ?

Comment: Where do you log foo.timer.seconds

Comment: Timer of undefined means, parent of timer, ie, foo is going undefined where ever you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` isn’t defined until the end of the `var foo = { ... };` statement. You could define these variables before defining `foo`.

```
var hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;
var foo = {
    timer: {
        hours, minutes, seconds,
        time: new Date( 1970, 0, 1, hours, minutes, seconds ).getTime()
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right, foo isn't defined until the end of the var foo = {...}

Comment: This is ugly. Doesn't allow storing the values in the object itself the way original intent seems to be

Comment: Yeah I agree, the suggestions in other answers are better.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are creating the foo object is incorrect... first create the object and use its properties, you are trying to refer the `foo` object in your time property when the variable `foo` hasn't been asigned yet..

```js
var foo =
{   
    "timer" : 
    {
        "hours" : 0, 
        "minutes" : 0, 
        "seconds" : 0,  
                            
    }
};

foo["time"] = new Date(1970, 0, 1, foo.timer.hours, foo.timer.minutes, foo.timer.seconds).getTime();

console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

foo.time = new Date(1970, 0, 1, foo.timer.hours, foo.timer.minutes, foo.timer.seconds).getTime()

you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying assign some values before those are initialize. You should split the declaration of the values and then you can add the `time` key/value function.

Hope this helps :>

```js
var foo =
{   
    "timer" : 
    {
        "hours" : 0, 
        "minutes" : 0, 
        "seconds" : 0                   
    }
};

foo.timer['time'] = new Date(1970, 0, 1, foo.timer.hours, foo.timer.minutes, foo.timer.seconds).getTime();   
console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is add a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to the object

```js
var foo =
{   
    "timer" : 
    {
        "hours" : 0, 
        "minutes" : 0, 
        "seconds" : 0, 
        get time(){
           return new Date(1970, 0, 1, this.hours, this.minutes, this.seconds).getTime()
        }                       
    }
};

console.log(foo.timer.time)
```